# Nuxt.js router doesn't seem to load the correct component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

We are trying out Nuxt.js for an app am having a bit of a problem getting their router to load the correct component. I have structured our directory to generate the following:

```
      path: "/articles/:id?",
      component: _241eccb7,
      name: "articles-id",
      children: [{
        path: "edit",
        component: _4bdace12,
        name: "articles-id-edit"
      }]
    }, {
```

The issue is that the articles-id-edit never get invoked. For `articles/123`, the article-id route is invoked and associated component. For `articles/123/edit`, the article-id route is invoked and the same component when I'd expect the `article-id-edit` route to be invoked with its corresponding component.

What am I not understanding? What would be a decent way to debug this (like `rake routes` in Rails or something). Is there a way I can make more explicit my routes rather than automagically creating?

Answer (score 0):

Is your file structure set up properly? Per the docs:

> To define the parent component of a nested route, you need to create a
>   Vue file with the same name as the directory which contain your
>   children views.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#nested-routes